# Division with Number type

Tags: java, types, arithmetic-expressions

I have a server call which returns values of type "Number".
This value needs to be transformed and stored.

Eg: Transformation = value/10( Here value is the response from the server)

These transformation could be different for different datapoints. For now, I consider the transformation to be (value/10)

```
Number modifiedValue = applyTransformation(event.getValue().getValue(),transformation);


private Number applyTransformation(Number value, String transformation) {
    Number dinominator = Integer.parseInt(transformation.substring(transformation.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
    
    Number modifiedValue = value/dinominator; //Produces an error

     return modifiedValue;


  }
```

Error : "The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Number, java.lang.Number"

Any suggestions to handle this please?

Comment: You cannot call the / operator on Number type instances. What you should pass to the method is an Int or a Double. Or cast the Number instance to one of these values inside the method

Comment: Number is abstract and particularly in this class is simply the base template for subclasses to extend from their own implementation as most methods are abstract and it has no class fields or instance fields so thereabout no state almost alike an interface.    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes divide operator not applicable for the argument java.lang.Number. But you can convert Number to java.math.BigDecimal you can apply this. Example code is below.

Output is :

5

5.0

5.0

5

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Number result = divideByNumber(10l, 2l);

    //Test data
    result = divideByNumber(10, 2l);
    System.out.println(result);

    result = divideByNumber(10.0, 2l);
    System.out.println(result);

    result = divideByNumber(10.0f, 2l);
    System.out.println(result);

    result = divideByNumber(new BigDecimal("10"), 2l);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static Number divideByNumber(Number n1, Number n2){
    return new BigDecimal(n1.toString()).divide(new BigDecimal(n2.toString()));
}
```